# Memory card is not showing all data

Tags: memory-card, data-corruption, panasonic

I have a Panasonic AG-AC90EN 1080p HD camera. I had recorded many video clips, then removed the memory card from camera and connected the memory card to my PC using SD card reader.

The problem is that when the memory card is in my camera it shows all 169 video clips and I'm able play a few clips from them, but when connected to my PC via the card reader there are only a few clips shown - also the memory card shows only 2GB of 29GB free while the data inside memory card is only 145MB.

Please help me get all the videos back. I don't know why is this happening

Comment: We have a number of questions about recovering photographs. However, video is somewhat different (and trickier). This site, however, isn't about video — you might try the general-purpose tech site in the same network, http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is happening but I would suggest some steps to do.

1) First of all, make sure your computer has an updated antivirus. Sometimes you need to run additional malware software, like malwarebytes, and other anti-spyware. There are some free antivirus online. Bitdefender online, nod 32 online. Use several, not just one.

Sometimes there is malware that tries to get into removable devices.

Scan your computer. Don't scan the SD card.

2) Try to use the usb cord instead of using a ssd card reader.

If you installed the software that came with your camera, in general terms is safer to transfer the files that way, because it recognizes different associated files, like previews.

3) Although there are some data recovery software, if the videos are really important go to a specialized company to try to recover the videos, because you just have one chance to do it. That is why I won't recommend any software.

The data loss could be either by software or a physical failure of the card. In the case that the failure is just by software it can be on 2 parts, the video itself or just the table info that find the file inside the memory.

4) Make some tests with new cards, and see if the camera is not the one that has the problem.